# How to Implement react-native-maps in Android

Tags: google-maps, react-native

hi I've been using the React-Native-Maps library from https://github.com/lelandrichardson/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/installation.md with a real android divice and i followed the installation but when i start to use CMD and write 'react-native run-andorid', i got error this msg.

```
:app:dexDebug
Unknown source file : UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
Unknown source file : com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v7/appcompat/R$anim;
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:579)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:535)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:517)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:164)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:504)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)

:app:dexDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: 
Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

help me plz!

Comment: are you using Mapview.polygon by any chance ?

Comment: i have no idea with Mapview.polygon..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably the problem is with gradle cache for Android. Try running the below command at the root of your project

`cd android && ./gradlew clean`